# pdftex.def error

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex, texniccenter

I'm just beginning with LaTeX, and I'm trying to understand how to include images in my documents. I'm working under TeXnicCenter. 
In the book I've bought they say that I should use the command `\includegraphics`. I've used the packages `calc` and `graphicx`, but the message `pdftex.def error` appears when I try to open an image and apparently LaTeX can't find my file.

LaTeX writes:

```
! package pdftex.def Error: File 'The name of the file' not found.
```

I don't have files under the `eps` format, but .jpg or .png. I've tried to use the package `epstopdf`, as recommended on this website, but I can't understand where I'm supposed to enter the option `-shell-escape`. And as this package is supposed to convert `eps` files to `pdf`, I don't see how it could help me anyway, as I'm trying to use JPEG and PNG files. So as you can see, little problem here ...

My code is basically this (I hope the problem doesn't come from other packages I would have used and were not compatible, but I don't think so):

```
\documentclass{report}   
\usepackage{calc, graphicx}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  


\begin{document} 

\includegraphics{C:/Users/Pictures/Lord of the Rings/Dimholt.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using miktex?

Comment: could you please put a minimal working example (MWE) to identify where the problem comes from? if you don't know how to make MWE, please check this link http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2288

Comment: To answer your question Ulrike Fisher, yes, I'm using miktex.

Comment: I'll include the code in my question, just a minute.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if I compile your given code with MiKTeX 2.9 (and using TeXnicCenter with compiling option `LaTeX->PDF`)  I get the same error you showed us.

[image]

This error simply tells you that the file `thefile.jpg` is not found and can therefore not be included to your document.

If I compile with added option `demo` to package `graphicx` the code compiles without error---of course, because LaTeX has not to search and clude a non existing file.

BTW, if I compile with `pdflatex` (that means the TeXnicCenter option `LaTeX->PDF` I do not need the other packages you added to your code.

Please see the following MWE, compiling without error:

```
\documentclass{report}

%\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % <============ no error, no file to include!
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % <====== only needed, if you have ti onclude *.eps files!
%\usepackage{grffile}


\begin{document} 

\includegraphics{thefile.jpg}

\end{document}
```

If I now add a file `thefile.jpg` into the same directory the tex code is and delete option `[demo]`, the image is included with no error.

If you want to include an `*.eps` file compiling with `pdflatex`, you need to uncomment package `epstopdf`. Then an file `thefile.eps` (you see the different extention `.eps`?) is converted to `thefile.pdf` and can be included.  But then you need to call it in your TeX code with `\includegraphics{thefile.eps}`.

Please see this image and check the red marked parts:

[image]

For me it seems you do missmatch some things, I'm right?

Comment: Okay!!! Now it's working. In a new document than the one I had already created it is working. I'll try to discover why it's not working in the other one... Long night ahead... I must have written Something wrong.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Actually, I think I understood why it wasn't working. If I add " "around the name of the file, and the command \string before the : of C:/User... in the name of the file, it does work. Maybe that's why it wasn't working at the beginning. Maybe it couldn't find the file because it couldn't distinguish the different elements in the name... Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: okay, I'll change the code of my question to show where the problem was. It was definitely the problem with the name.

Comment: Mensch solution doesn't work for me. Any help ? how was this resolved?

Comment: @mindless Well, what did you do exactly, which code do you use, which tex editor? Perhaps you can ask a new follow up question better explaining your issue ... Have you tried using `""`?

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple update problem. I had a similar issue and when I updated the MiKTeX, the issue was resolved.